# Is there a command that allows me to set a prefered IP Address for an adapter?

Tags: windows, networking, batch, cmd.exe, ipv4

I've got some customers who should use a specific IP in their network adapter, but manually setting it is a pain sometimes.
So I would like to know if there's a shell command / batch that allows me to set it without having to open "Network" -> "Adapter Setting" -> "Ipv4" -> "Ip Address".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-13513-how-to-change-ip-address-from-command-prompt)

The command is: 
to change IP and default gateway:

```
netsh int ip set address "local area connection" static 192.168.0.101 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.254 1
```

to change DNS:

```
netsh int ip set dns "local area connection" static 192.168.0.254 primary
```

This is assuming 3 things.

1) The network adapter you're trying to change the IP for is "local area connection". It could also be "local area connection 2" or "wireless network connection". Look in your control panel for the correct name

2) The IP you want to set is 192.168.0.101, change this to whatever IP to want to use.

3) The default gateway and dns are the same IP. If you are using some kind of router they usually are. Change this to match your network config found with the command ipconfig /all

Comment: appreciate it. Can I also get the adapter and store in a variable? To fully automate it?