# windows 7: assign static IP address

Tags: windows-7, windows, ip, ip-address, ifconfig

I want to connect two laptops with a crossover Ethernet cable, in order to synchronize them with `ntp`. One laptop runs Windows 7, the other one Ubuntu.

On Ubuntu, in order to assign a static IP address to an interface, I just do:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Is there a similar way for Windows, from the `cmd`?

Comment: Also: [Is there a command that allows me to set a prefered IP Address for an adapter?](http://superuser.com/questions/698676/is-there-a-command-that-allows-me-to-set-a-prefered-ip-address-for-an-adapter?lq=1)

Comment: Aim for one question per question please. :)  FYI This secondary request: "is there anything else I should do for the two pc's to communicate?" is too broad, and is not really a problem you need to solve (yet).

Comment: yeah, you're right. I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NETSH to set static IP addresses, see http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/257748/en

Syntax: netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static ipaddr subnetmask gateway metric
Sample: netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1

Substitute "Local Area Connection" with the name of the network adapter as needed.

You may need to deactivate Windows firewall.